# Python compare two columns, if one is blank count as a match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare

This should be simple but I couldn't find an example - I have a dataframe with lots of pairs of columns. Col1a needs to be compared to Col1b, Col2a needs to be compared to Col2b, etc.
If one of the columns is blank, I want to count it as a match - that is, there is no conflict between the two columns. I only want to show a mismatch if both columns are filled and have different values

Sample data, including the two desired output columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('A', 'A', 'E', 'F', 0, 1),
('C', None, 'G', 'G', 0, 0),
('B', 'C', 'H', None, 1, 0),
('D', None, None, 'J', 0, 0)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1a', 'col1b', 'col2a', 'col2b', 'col1_mismatch', 'col2_mismatch'])

print(df)
```

I've tried some np.where attempts and got "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." errors

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
# Generate input dataframe, df_in
df_in = df[['col1a', 'col1b', 'col2a', 'col2b']]

(df_in.join(df_in.groupby(df_in.columns.str[:-1], axis=1).nunique()
                 .gt(1).astype(int).add_suffix('_mismatch')))
```

Output:

```
  col1a col1b col2a col2b  col1_mismatch  col2_mismatch
0     A     A     E     F              0              1
1     C  None     G     G              0              0
2     B     C     H  None              1              0
3     D  None  None     J              0              0
```

Details:

Use groupby to group on the first four characters in column header then count the unique values.  If greater than 1 then you have a mismatch.

Comment: Nice one, a generalization: `tmp = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)', n=1, expand=True), axis=1).drop(columns='_mismatch', level=1) ; df.filter(regex='(?<!_mismatch)$').join(tmp.groupby(level=0, axis=1).nunique().gt(1).astype(int))`

Comment: Woah... a @mozway compliment is like worth 500 reputation points.  Made my day!